# How to make the edge less harsh?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using Photoshop and I'm colouring in the sea in my image as you can see below. I'm using a combination of the magic wand tool and the quick select tool and then using the 'fill' option. I'm very new to Photoshop. Does anyone know a way to make the edge less harsh? It just seems very jarring at the moment and I'm wondering how to soften/blend it in better. 
[image: Example]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you tried feathering your selection before filling it?  (hint: Select > Modify > Feather)